# compare 2 CSV files using Python

Tags: python

I have 2 CSV files where employee ID is the primary key. In the new file there will be some changes like phone number or address change. I am trying to do with Dict compare. Please guide me.

```
Old file -> 12345, Peter, 765 darwin BLVD, 326-967-4330
New file -> 12345, Peter, 765 darwin LLVD, 339-440-3330`
```

I want to compare both the files line by line using the emp ID.

Comment: Looks like you want `csv.DictReader`. Have a look at the docs for the `csv` module. There are useful examples.

Comment: But the rows might differ from old file and new file. I need to loop through the EMpl ID.There might be new rows as well

Comment: I know that. Use the `.csv` module to create 2 `dict`s of `dict`s (*key:* EmplID, *value:* `dict` supplied by `csv.DictReader`), one representing each input file. Then loop through the outer `dict` keys to find the differences. You will have to go through both in turn. Scanning the new data will tell you about additions but you need to scan the old data to find deletions.

Comment: I recommend you to read them as two data frames and compare them, it will be easier.

Comment: Please tell us when you compare both files based on ID and then what you should do if there is a match between the ID in the old and the new CSV?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind installing [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), here's one way:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

old = '''\
empid, name, address, phone
12345, Peter, 765 darwin BLVD, 326-967-4330
23456, John, 123 Sesame st, 123-456-7890
'''

new = '''\
empid, name, address, phone
12345, Peter, 765 darwin LLVD, 339-440-3330
23456, John, 123 Sesame st, 123-456-7890
'''

old_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(old), skipinitialspace=True)
new_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(new), skipinitialspace=True)

df = old_df.merge(new_df, on=['empid'], suffixes=('_old', '_new'))

print(df.query('name_old != name_new or address_old != address_new or phone_old != phone_new'))
```